# use post html after rending html

Tags: javascript, forms, post, flask, flask-wtforms

Using flask and WT forms I am trying to get the user input in a form and  redirecting user input to another route, there using the input in functions which will get some dict of data.

I want this data to use in a WT form. Once I saw the data and checked all fine. I want to save it as new entry for database.

Problem: after rending the form this I am not able to process to as post request.

```
@app.route('/', method =[POST,GET])
def home():
    forms = inputForms(request.form)
    if form_validate() and request.POST:
         value=forms.input.data
         redirect(url_for(/edit, value=value) 
    return render_template('input.html')  -- Initial page where getting user input 
  @app.route('/edit', method =[POST,GET])
   def edit(value):
       data= getdata(value)
       if data == 'error':
            return render_template('error.html')
       else:
          form=request.form(data=data)
          return render_template('data.html', form=form
          if form_validate() and request.POST:
               save ()
```

I'd like to see that once render the form how can I use it submit.

I am able to get the forms but once return I am not able to move ahead on the save options

Comment: if you got to your `edit` func through `redirect`, i don't think it's still a `POST` and so the `if request.POST` fails.

Comment: thanks for response can you suggest something other way i am new to python as well coding

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, you can change your post action. so your form is `POST`ed to another route.

```
<form method="POST" action="{{url_for('edit')}}">
{{ form.csrf_token }}
{{ form.name.label }} {{ form.name(size=20) }}
<input type="submit" value="Go">
```

Using the above in your template, then you can move your functionality for validation to that `route`.

```
@app.route('/edit', method =[POST,GET])
def edit():
   if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():
      pass
```

this way, you can handle everything within the `edit` route.
then your `home` route can change to just rendering the form.

```
@app.route('/', method =[POST,GET])
def home():
    forms = inputForms(request.form)
    return render_template('input.html')
```

and you should have a `trailing slash` for your `routes`. so it's better to have your routes as:

```
@app.route('/edit/', method =[POST,GET])
def edit():
    pass
```